# Setting LIA logic in z3

Tags: python, z3, z3py

I'm trying to use a tactic specific for LIA instances using the python interface. I have tried to use:

```
solver = Tactic('lia').solver()
```

Unfortunately I received the message "unknown tactic 'lia'". The same works when instead I use 'qflia'. What can I do in order to use the best possible tactic for this kind of instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no custom tactic for LIA problems, but there is one for QF_LIA (i.e., quantifier free LIA) and it is called "qflia", so it shouldn't report an error on that. This works for me:

```
from z3 import *

s = Tactic('qflia').solver()

x = Int('x')
s.add(x < 5)
print(s.check())
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I was just wondering if there is something more specific for this kind of instances (I was already using 'qflia'). Moreover, is there any configuration option I could set in order to speed up the performance of the solver on LIA instances?

Comment: There is no magic option that would make everything fast. You'd have to take a close look at what your instances look like and whether there's an efficient algorithm for that.